# how to configure socket io in server to get acknowledge (SocketIOCallback) from ios socket

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

I am developing a chat app in ios with node.js and socket.io. I use SocketIOCallback to send acknowledgement. But i don't getting any acknowledgement on server.js. Here is the code i use to send acknowledge

```
SocketIOCallback cb = ^(id argsData) {
    NSDictionary *response = argsData;
    // do something with response
    NSLog(@"ack arrived: %@", response);
};

[socketIO sendEvent:@"message" withData:values andAcknowledge:cb];
```

server.js

```
socket.on('message', function(postMessage,callback){
    console.log(callback);
    //callback('okkk');
    console.log('username-->'+  socket.username);
    console.log('ID-->'+  socket.id);
    io.sockets.emit("pvt",socket.username,postMessage+socket.username);
    io.sockets.emit("pvt",socket.username,postMessage+socket.username);      
});
```

when printing console.log(callback) it show unknown in terminal

How to configure server.js to get these acknowledgement from ios app. Or how to send acknowledgement from server to ios app and vice versa  Please help me to solve these problem with example. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution which consists on changing emit method to emitEvent. Hope it really help you.